# On click of radio button wants splited value output in drop down list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need a solution 
I have two radio buttons for measurement in cm and inch.

```
<html>
   <lable class="radioinline">Measurement(cm)</lable>
   <input type="radio" name="size" id="radio0"></input>
   <lable class="radioinline">Measurement(inch)</lable>
   <input type="radio" name="size" id="radio1"></input>
</html>
```

and one dropdown list box with below listed values in hidden form.

```
<select id="measure" name="chest" hidden>
   <option>70cm/27Inch</option>
   <option>71cm/28Inch</option>
   <option>72cm/29Inch</option>
</select>
```

my requirement is on click of radio button either I get the values in cm or in inch in dropdown list which is actually in format of "cm/inch".

Please help to resolve it.

Comment: Bear in mind that `<lable>` is spelled `<label>` :)

Comment: you want to change the values displayed in select box or you are displaying the text some where and you want it according to radio button selected??

Comment: Values are already there in drop down list in hidden format. on select of radio button wants the output in in select box only.

Comment: @Ajinkya just to be clear.. if I select _Measurement(cm)_ then you want options is select to be changed to _70cm_,_71cm_ and _72cm_ ..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the select option while clicking radio button.
Try this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#radio0").click(function() {
    var measure = $("#measure");
    measure.show();
    measure.find("option").remove();
    measure.append("<option>70cm</option>");
    measure.append("<option>71cm</option>");
    measure.append("<option>72cm</option>");
  });
  $("#radio1").click(function() {
    var measure = $("#measure");
    measure.show();
    measure.find("option").remove();
    measure.append("<option>27Inch</option>");
    measure.append("<option>28Inch</option>");
    measure.append("<option>29Inch</option>");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radioinline">Measurement(cm)</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="radio0" />
<label class="radioinline">Measurement(inch)</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="radio1" />
<select id="measure" name="chest" hidden>
  <option>70cm/27Inch</option>
  <option>71cm/28Inch</option>
  <option>72cm/29Inch</option>
</select>
```

Hope this will help you.

**Modified Answer**

Store the value in data property for each option and use that value while clicking the radio buttons

Try this code.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#radio0").click(function() {
    var measure = $("#measure"),
      options = measure.find("option");
    options.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).data("value").split("/")[0];
      $(this).text(value);
    });
    measure.show();
  });
  $("#radio1").click(function() {
    var measure = $("#measure"),
      options = measure.find("option");
    options.each(function() {
      var value = $(this).data("value").split("/")[1];
      $(this).text(value);
    });
    measure.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="radioinline">Measurement(cm)</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="radio0" />
<label class="radioinline">Measurement(inch)</label>
<input type="radio" name="size" id="radio1" />
<select id="measure" name="chest" hidden>
  <option data-value="70cm/27Inch">70cm/27Inch</option>
  <option data-value="71cm/28Inch">71cm/28Inch</option>
  <option data-value="72cm/29Inch">72cm/29Inch</option>
</select>
```

Comment: It is working.. but i have n number of records. can we use split method which I can apply for all option values..I am trying but not getting desired output.